# Cannot retrieve array data in js

Tags: javascript, arrays

As the name suggests I cannot retrieve array data in js. The code I have is var iconAttribs = document.querySelectorAll(icon);

```
var file = iconAttribs[icns].getAttribute("data-file");
$(document).on("dblclick", iconAttribs,function() {
    new createFrame(350,505,file,true,"Application Test!");
});
```

The problem is that the code shows this:

> file:AnosCalculator/AnosCalculator.html! 
>   file:PacMan/PatrickMan.html!
>   file:AnosBrowser/AnosBrowser.html!

whne I do `console.log("file:"+file+"!");`.
This is what is should get but when I apply this to my function `createFrame` with parameters `width,height,content_src and isResizable`.`

The var `file` is used as the fill in of `content_src`. But this does not work.What it should do is load up an app with the specified app src based on the data it retrieves from the data-File attribute in one of my .icon divs. each icon has a different value. All icon images work but not the files. So basically the icon with the calculator image should open the calculator app becaouse of this code: `$(".tdata0").append("<div class = 'icon' data-file='AnosCalculator/AnosCalculator.html' data-iconFile='AnosCalculator/calculator.png'></div>");` but doesn't any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The second param for `jquery.on` method should be a CSS selector (check http://api.jquery.com/on/). Then you should have somthing like this:

```
$(document).on("dblclick", 'your CSS selector here',function() {
    new createFrame(350,505,file,true,"Application Test!");
});
```

Comment: I do icon is var with the value of ".icon" and anways the app opens but only dislays the last data-file attribute item from the top of the file.

Comment: According to your code, you are providing an array instead of CSS seletor (string) ... if you could provide a JSfiddle I can take a look

Comment: Too complicated for jsfiddle but to simplify the explanation, the code takes data-file attribute from each .icon and use  to load the relevant app but I might not be loading up each icons relevant app file?